# Cannot install NetBeans 8 in Ubuntu 14

Tags: server, java, sudo, netbeans

I am trying to install NetBeans 8 in Ubuntu 14. When I execute the .sh file using ( I have already set the file as executable )

```
./netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh
```

I get this ( Out of memory error )

[image]

I tried using

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1024m -Xms512m"
```

but the same thing happens. 
But if I try to install it using *sudo*

```
sudo ./netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh
```

installation window starts normally

[image]

I want to install NetBeans as normal user. As you can see in the screenshot it shows *I have NetBeans already installed*. But this is installed using *sudo*, so when I start NetBeans as normal user & create a project I cannot deploy it to the Application Server which are also installed in the root's location.

I know I can change the App Server location or I can use some other server altogether, but it is now its bugging me, that why I can't install it as normal user.

I have also put up this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229204/cannot-install-netbeans-8-in-ubuntu-14).

Answer (score 1):

**First, Remove your previous installed version.**

Now follow this

### Step by step guide

1. Download Netbeans from [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/), in my example, I'm using the "All" bundle.
2. Go into your download folder, E.G.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
3. Make the installer executable

   ```
   chmod +x netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh
   ```
4. Start the installation

   ```
   sudo ./netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh
   ```
5. Change the installation target

   ```
   /opt/netbeans-8.0.2
   ```

   [image]
6. Finish the installation and start Netbeans via your Launcher

   [image]
7. Create a sample app, E.G. PHP TodoList and start the application on the build in server

   [image]

   [image]