# Unable to get Netbean installer

Tags: software-installation, netbeans

I'm not able to get netbeans installer after typing command:

```
./jdk-8u60-nb-8_0_2-linux-x64.sh
```

Please help me..

Comment: If you want to install netbeans refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75549/how-do-i-install-netbeans)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot install NetBeans 8 in Ubuntu 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/673213/cannot-install-netbeans-8-in-ubuntu-14)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you need to make it executable, which you can do with `chmod +x jdk-8u60-nb-8_0_2-linux-x64.sh`.